# Replace fileds with AWK by using a different file as translation list

Tags: replace, awk, user-defined-functions

I am using `awk` in Windows. I have a script called `test.awk`.
This script should read a file and replace a certain filed (key) with a value.
The key->value list is in a file called `translate.txt`.

It's structure is like this:

```
e;Emil    
f;Friedrich
g;Gustaf
h;Heinrich
i;Ida
```

In a simple example, my input file would be

```
e,111    
f,222
g,333
h,444
i,555
..
```

so the output should be

```
Emil,111
Friedrich,222
Gustaf,333
Heinrich,444
Ida,555
..
```

The script I an having is using a user function `key2value` to do the replacement, but I don't succeed in giving this function another file `translate.txt` as a source. See my code:

```
{   
    FS=","
    d=key2value($1)
    print d "," $2
}

function key2value(b)
{
    #this should use another file, not the currently processed one
    FILENAME="translate.txt"  

begin
{
    FS=";"

    if ($1=b)
    { 
       return $2
    }

end 

}
```

Another thing, the FS is buggy to, it starts working from the second line only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simple one-liner will do the trick:

```
awk  'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print a[$1],$2}' FS=',|;' OFS=',' translate input
Emil,111
Friedrich,222
Gustaf,333
Heinrich,444
Ida,555
```

In script form:

```
BEGIN {                # The BEGIN block is executed before the files are read
    FS="[,;]"          # Set the FS to be either a comma or semi-colon
    OFS=","            # Set the OFS (output field separator) to be a comma
}
FNR==NR {              # FNR==NR only true when reading the first file
   key2value[$1]=$2;   # Create associative array of key,value pairs 
   next                # Grab the next line in the first file
} 
{                      # Now in the second file, print looked up value and $2 
    print key2value[$1],$2
}
```

Run like:

```
awk -f translate.awk translate.txt input.txt
```

---

There are numerous error with your script, you should take a read of [**Effective AWK Programming**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/).

Comment: Good. This kind of problem has been solved many many times with `awk` in this forum. It's a standard.

Comment: Thank a lot, you mighty god of awk!

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (Windows quoting):

```
sed -r "s#(\S+);(\S+)#/^\1,/s/.*,(\\S+)/\2,\\1/#" file1|sed -rf - file2
```

Shell session:

```
>type file1 file2

file1


e;Emil
f;Friedrich
g;Gustaf
h;Heinrich
i;Ida

file2


e,111
f,222
g,333
h,444
i,555

>sed -r "s#(\S+);(\S+)#/^\1,/s/.*,(\\S+)/\2,\\1/#" file1|sed -rf - file2
Emil,111
Friedrich,222
Gustaf,333
Heinrich,444
Ida,555
```